# THREE.js Triangle is Black

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, geometry

So i was using THREE.JS and created a triangle. But even though i gave it color: 0xFF0000, it appears black on Screen.

Here is my Script:

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 500;
    scene.add(camera);

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry(200,200,200);
    var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(200,0,0);   // Vector3 used to specify position
    var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(-100,0,0);
    var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(0,50,0);   // 2d = all vertices in the same plane.. z = 0

    // Push vertices represented by position vectors
    geometry.vertices.push(v1);
    geometry.vertices.push(v2);
    geometry.vertices.push(v3);

    // Push face, defined with vertices in counter clock-wise order
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 1));

    // Create a material and combine with geometry to create our mesh
    var redMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
    var triangle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, redMat);
    scene.add(triangle);

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}

function render() {

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Hope you can find the mistake i made. I am sure it's just something really stupid.

Comment: Works fine for me. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ProgramFOX/cKu42/

Comment: Okay, that is wierd. In browser for me, it it displayed black. But yes. on JSFiddle it's red...

Comment: Which browser are you using? And are you using the latest version of Three.js? For me, the Fiddle worked fine in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari (not in IE, because IE doesn't support WebGL).

Comment: I am using the newest Version of Three.js and Chrome. The Triangle is displayed, but only in Black. On JSFiddle with the same code it is displayed red.

Comment: Try to put your script in the `window.onload` event, as in the fiddle.

Comment: You're missing Ambient light. var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c); scene.add(ambientLight);

Answer (score 2):

late to the party...but for all who come after me.
The issue here is the type of material used

change

```
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
```

to

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
```

and it will show up red

Answer (score 1):

Even I've struggled from this problem for sometime. The solution for me was to add an ambient light to the scene if you're using Lambert Material.

Just add:

```
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(light);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add `computeFaceNormals` call upon geometry object:

> geometry.computeFaceNormals();

**from* https://stackoverflow.com/a/49226898/2154075

Comment: Working now. This was what I was missing. Why is IvanM not getting any upvotes?